# OpenCv with Android studio 1.3+ using new gradle - undefined reference

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having trouble using native OpenCv 2.4.11 (3.0.0 is also ok) with Android Studio 1.3+, with new ndk support. All tutorials about .mk files, but I want to use it with new experimental gradle.
Using Kiran answer [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)
I achived to work fine in java. Also I have changed 
gradle-wrapper.properties: 

    `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip`

build.gradle(application):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
```

build.gradle(module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "android.overloaded.nativetestv4"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }

    android.ndk{
        moduleName = "mymodule"
        ldLibs += ['log']
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11" 
        cppFlags += "-fexceptions"
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/DevAndroid/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString()
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/DevAndroid/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv")}".toString()

        ldLibs += ["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"] //added z
        stl = "stlport_static"//"gnustl_shared" changed to stlport static
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors { //added all productFlavors code
        create("arm") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi"
                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\" //"-L" +
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"
            }
        }
        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\" //"-L" +

               ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
               ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"
            }
         }
         create("fat") {
         }
     }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
        compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')
    }
```

With this changes I can call my native dummy function in c++ file under jni folder. Also `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>` and others are supported by CLion... When I declare cv::Mat mat; gives me this error:

```
Linker failed while linking libmymodule.so failed.
C:\DevAndroid\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: error: undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:\DevAndroid\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

c++ code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "helpers.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> //This is supported by CLion
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_android_overloaded_nativetestv4_MainActivity_FuncV1(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {
    cv::Mat mat; //causing error

    string s = "Cpp v1 - succ ";
    return env->NewStringUTF(s.data());
}

}
```

**Update**
- added "z" to ldLibs
- added android.productFlavors block

Now compilation is successfull, application starts for second and then crashes with this messages
Event log:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Error while starting native debug session: Unable to find process for android.overloaded.nativetestv4 on device huawei-huawei_y530_u00-64a6513ccd8e
```

Debug info:

```
Restart ADB integration and try again
Waiting for process: android.overloaded.nativetestv4
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: run-as android.overloaded.nativetestv4 mkdir -p /data/data/android.overloaded.nativetestv4/lldb/bin
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: cat /data/local/tmp/lldb-server | run-as android.overloaded.nativetestv4 sh -c 'cat > /data/data/android.overloaded.nativetestv4/lldb/bin/lldb-server; chmod 700 /data/data/android.overloaded.nativetestv4/lldb/bin/lldb-server'
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: rm /data/local/tmp/lldb-server
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: cat /data/local/tmp/start_lldb_server.sh | run-as android.overloaded.nativetestv4 sh -c 'cat > /data/data/android.overloaded.nativetestv4/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh; chmod 700 /data/data/android.overloaded.nativetestv4/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh'
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: rm /data/local/tmp/start_lldb_server.sh
Now Launching Native Debug Session
Error while starting native debug session: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find process for android.overloaded.nativetestv4 on device huawei-huawei_y530_u00-64a6513ccd8e
```

log:

```
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 3077 (ed.nativetestv4)
```

Comment: You're pointing to the location of the headers, but not to the location of the actual libraries. Including '-L<opencv libraries location>' and then the names of the libraries you are using in the ldLibraries should work.

Comment: There are .so and .a in directories: src/main/jniLibs/<abi>. Isn't that enough? I'm newbie in android and I don't understand much what is happening in gradle files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After few weeks of pain, I succed. Here is my correct code for Android studio 1.3.1, OpenCv 2.4.11. First you should do this [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)
 (don't use paths which contains white space, both for project and opencv extraction folder) then, for opencv to be native:

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

build.gradle(application):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
```

build.gradle(module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "android.overloaded.nativetestv4"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }


    android.ndk{
        moduleName = "mymodule"
        ldLibs += ['log']
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
        cppFlags += "-fexceptions"
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/DevAndroid/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString()
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/DevAndroid/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv")}".toString()



//        ldFlags += linkOpt
        ldLibs += ["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"]// , "ibopencv_core"
        stl = "gnustl_shared"//"gnustl_static"//"gnustl_shared"//"stlport_static"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\" //"-L" +

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"

            }
        }
        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\" //"-L" +

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"

            }
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "x86"
            }
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "mips"
            }
        }
        create("fat") {

        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')
}
```

.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "helpers.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif



JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_android_overloaded_nativetestv4_MainActivity_FuncV1(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {

    cv::Mat mat(33,22, 1);

    string s = "Cpp v1 - succ, rows#:" + Helpers::ToStringNum(mat.rows);
    Helpers::Log(s);

    return env->NewStringUTF(s.data());
}

}
```

.java

```
package android.overloaded.nativetestv4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("mymodule");
    }

    public static native String FuncV1();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, FuncV1(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInfo)).setText(FuncV1());
    }
```

**Update for Android Studio 1.5.1, OpenCV 3.1**
1. First you should do this [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio) (don't use paths which contains white space, both for project and opencv extraction folder), after that you should have normal working Java app
2. Change build.gradle in project root:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

3. Change gradle-wrapper.properties:

> ```
> distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
> distributionPath=wrapper/dists
> zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
> zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
> ```

4. Change build.gradle in opencv module:

   > ```
   > apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
   >
   > model {
   >     android {
   >         compileSdkVersion = 23
   >         buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
   >         defaultConfig.with {
   >             minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
   >             targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
   >         }
   >
   >
   >     }
   >
   >     android.buildTypes {
   >         release {
   >             minifyEnabled = false
   >             proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```
5. Change build.gradle in app module:

   > ```
   > apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
   >
   > model {
   >     android {
   >         compileSdkVersion = 23
   >         buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
   >
   >         defaultConfig.with {
   >             applicationId = "android.overloaded.opencv31v1" //Name of package
   >             minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
   >             targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
   >             versionCode = 1
   >             versionName = "1.0"
   >
   >         }
   >     }
   >
   >     android.ndk {
   >         moduleName = "native" // Name of C++ module, for System.loadLibrary("native")
   >         cppFlags.add("-std=c++11") // Add provisions to allow C++11 functionality
   >         cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
   >         // YOUR OPENCV DIRECTORY!!!
   >         cppFlags.add("-I${file("C:/DevAndroid/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString()) 
   >         ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"])
   >         stl = "gnustl_shared"
   >     }
   >
   >     android.buildTypes {
   >         release {
   >             minifyEnabled = false
   >             proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
   >         }
   >     }
   >
   >     android.productFlavors {
   >         create("arm") {
   >             ndk.with{
   >                 abiFilters.add("armeabi")
   >
   >                 File curDir = file('./')
   >                 curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
   >                 String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\"
   >
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
   >
   >             }
   >         }
   >         create("armv7") {
   >             ndk.with {
   >                 abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
   >
   >                 File curDir = file('./')
   >                 curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
   >                 String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\"
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
   >                 ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")
   >
   >             }
   >         }
   >     }
   >     android.sources{
   >         main{
   >             jni{
   >                 source{
   >                     srcDirs += ['src/main/jniMy']
   >                 }
   >             }
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > dependencies {
   >     compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: [$/*.jar/$])
   >     compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1" //Do not use 23.2.0 
   >     compile project(":openCVLibrary310")
   > }
   > ```
6. Create dir app/src/main/jniMy, this is place for yours .cpp files
7. Optionally create file chelper.c in jniMy, with this code:

   > ```
   > #ifndef OPENCV31V1_CHELPER_H
   > #define OPENCV31V1_CHELPER_H
   >
   > #include <jni.h>
   > #include <vector>
   > #include <string>
   > #include <sstream>
   > #include <android/log.h>
   >
   > using namespace std;
   >
   > class Helpers{
   > public:
   >     template <typename T>
   >     static string ToStringNum(T tNumber){
   >         ostringstream ostrStream;
   >         ostrStream << tNumber;
   >         return ostrStream.str();
   >     }
   >
   >     static void Log(string s){
   >         __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "My", s.data());
   >     }
   >     static void Log(std::exception ee){
   >         string s = "Exception: " + string(ee.what()) ;
   >         __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "My", s.data());
   >     }
   >
   >     static long Time(){
   >         struct timespec now;
   >         clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
   >         return (long)((int64_t)now.tv_sec * 1000LL + now.tv_nsec /1000000LL);
   >     }
   >     static string Time(long iTime){
   >         return ToStringNum(Time() - iTime) + "ms";
   >     }
   >
   > };
   > #endif //OPENCV31V1_CHELPER_H
   > ```
8. Create file native_exporter.cpp in jniMy, with this code:

   > ```
   > #include <jni.h>
   > #include <string>
   > #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
   > #include "chelper.h"
   >
   > extern "C"{
   > JNIEXPORT jstring     JNICALLJava_android_overloaded_opencv31v1_MainActivity_FuncV1(JNIEnv *env,
   > jclass type) {
   >
   >     cv::Mat mat(33,22, CV_32FC2);
   >
   >     string s = "Cpp v1 - succ, rows#:" +Helpers::ToStringNum(mat.rows);
   >     Helpers::Log(s);
   >     auto i = 5;
   >     for (int i2 : {1,3,5}){
   >         Helpers::Log(Helpers::ToStringNum(i2));
   >     }
   >
   >     return env->NewStringUTF(s.data());
   > }
   > }
   > ```
9. Code in MainActivity.java:

   > ```
   > package android.overloaded.opencv31v1;
   >
   > import android.os.Bundle;
   > import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   > import android.util.Log;
   > import android.view.SurfaceView;
   > import android.widget.TextView;
   > import android.widget.Toast;
   >
   > import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
   > import org.opencv.core.CvType;
   > import org.opencv.core.Mat;
   >
   > public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
   > {
   >     private static void Log(String sMsg){Log.i("My", "MainActivity." + sMsg );}
   >
   >     static{
   >         System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
   >         System.loadLibrary("native");
   >     }
   >
   >     public native String FuncV1();
   >     JavaCameraViewCustom2 _javaCameraView; //Similar to JavaCameraView
   >
   >     @Override
   >     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   >     {
   >         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   >         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   >         if(getSupportActionBar() != null)getSupportActionBar().hide();
   >         String sRes = FuncV1();
   >         Toast.makeText(this, sRes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   >
   >         ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInfo)).setText(sRes);
   >
   >         _javaCameraView = (JavaCameraViewCustom2)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
   >         _javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
   >         _javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
   >
   >     }
   >
   >     @Override
   >     protected void onResume()
   >     {
   >         super.onResume();
   >         _javaCameraView.enableView();
   >     }
   >
   >     @Override
   >     protected void onPause()
   >     {
   >         super.onPause();
   >         _javaCameraView.disableView();
   >     }
   >
   >     Mat _imgBgrTemp;
   >     @Override
   >     public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
   >     {
   >         _imgBgrTemp = new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
   >     }
   >
   >     @Override
   >     public void onCameraViewStopped()
   >     {
   >         _imgBgrTemp.release();
   >     }
   >
   >     @Override
   >     public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
   >     {
   >         _imgBgrTemp = inputFrame.rgba();
   >         return _imgBgrTemp;
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

Android Studio will ask you to change jdk, also it will install new gradle, you should do everything it ask.

Comment: Hi I'm having trouble with the ` OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Specified descriptor extractor type is not supported.) in static cv::javaDescriptorExtractor* cv::javaDescriptorExtractor::create(int), file /builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_manual.hpp, line 374` can you help me with this?

Comment: I found this page about BRIEF bug http://code.opencv.org/issues/4419 in Opencv 3.0. Maybe other Descriptors/Extractors are also affected. You could try to use constructor: BriefDescriptorExtractor brief = BriefDescriptorExtractor(32);

Comment: What do you mean by (module) and (application) ? Module = openCVLibrary and Application  = app ? Or application is the project's build.gradle ? Ty!

Comment: Also, I'm having problem with the #include "helpers.h"
What exactly is this ?

Comment: @GeraldoNeto Header file helpers.h contains just functions for logging. I created that file, it's unimportant, just delete '#include "helpers.h"'.