# OpenCV in new Android Studio NDK

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I am trying to create NDK application dependent on OpenCV with new experimental gradle plugin in Android Studio but I can't really setup my `build.gradle` correctly.

My NDK setup in `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
/*
 * native build settings
 */
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "nonfree_jni"
    stl = "gnustl_static"
    cppFlags += "-I${opencv_path}".toString()    
}
```

where `opencv_path` is path to my OpenCV Android SDK (include directory)

If I open my `.cpp` file, the OpenCV classes and files are properly colored and everything looks OK but when I try to build project a lot of "undefined reference: cv::something" occurs.

I did not find any tutorial to run OpenCV in Android Studio (only that with manual ndk-build command) and don't really know how to fix this. Some stackoverflow post said that this errors happens when I don't point to `OpenCV.mk` in my `Android.mk` configuration but I obviously don't have this option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171259/opencv-with-android-studio-1-3-using-new-gradle-undefined-reference) helps.

Comment: @mvai thanks! It helped a lot. You should write it as answer and i will accept it

Comment: I know nothing about android-ndk and I am not able to interpret that (bad quality) answer :-) just did the search for you.

Comment: This is not only duplicate, it's outdated. Android Studio 2.3 has integrated **ndk-build** to fully resolve such issues.