# Migrating project to new experimental gradle plugin 0.6.0-alpha3 -> 0.6.0-alpha5

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I try to migrate my Android project to new experimental gradle plugin. I followed instructions at [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) page. I made changes in required files, but I have an error when I try to Sync project with gradle files.

> Error:Exception thrown while executing model rule: BaseComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createBinaryTasks

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

def opencv_modules = ["shape", "stitching", "objdetect", "superres", "videostab", "calib3d", "features2d", "highgui", "videoio", "imgcodecs", "video", "photo", "ml", "imgproc", "flann", "core", "hal"]
def opencv_third_parties = [ "liblibjpeg", "liblibpng", "liblibtiff", "liblibwebp", "liblibjasper", "libIlmImf", "libtbb"]

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.company.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "0.1"
            buildConfigFields.with {
                create() {
                    type = "int"
                    name = "VALUE"
                    value = "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "MyModule"
        toolchain = "gcc"
        toolchainVersion = "4.9"
        //toolchain = "clang"
        //toolchainVersion = "3.6"
        // Note that CFlags has a capital C, which is inconsistent with
        // the naming convention of other properties.  This is a
        // technical limitation that will be resolved
        CFlags.add("-DCUSTOM_DEFINE")
        cppFlags.add("-DOS_ANDROID")
        cppFlags.add("-D__ANDROID__")
        cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
        cppFlags.add("-DES2")
        cppFlags.add("-DES2")
        cppFlags.add("-I"+ project(':MyProject').getProjectDir() + "/../../../third-party/readerwriterqueue")

        cppFlags.add("-std=c++14")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-frtti")
        cppFlags.add("-fsigned-char")
        cppFlags.add("-fPIC")
        cppFlags.add("-fvisibility=hidden")
        cppFlags.add("-ffunction-sections")
        cppFlags.add("-fdata-sections")
        ldLibs.add("log")
        ldLibs.add("EGL")
        ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
        ldLibs.add("atomic")
        ldLibs.add("z")
        ldFlags.add("-Wl,--gc-sections")

        stl = "gnustl_shared"
        //stl = "stlport_shared" <-- currently no thread header
        //stl = "c++_shared" <-- clang
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable = true
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
        release {
            debuggable = false
            minifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles .add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = false
            }
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
                println "*** building for armv7: " + abiFilters
                abiFilters.each { targetAbi ->
                    opencv_modules.each { module ->
                        def libPath = project(':MyProject').getProjectDir().absolutePath
                        libPath += "/../../../third-party/opencv_android/sdk/native/libs/"
                        libPath += targetAbi
                        libPath += "/libopencv_"
                        libPath += module + ".a"
                        //println libPath
                        ldLibs.add(libPath)
                    }
                    opencv_third_parties.each { module ->
                        def libPath = project(':MyProject').getProjectDir().absolutePath
                        libPath +=  "/../../../third-party/opencv_android/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/"
                        libPath += targetAbi
                        libPath += "/"
                        libPath += module + ".a"
                        //println libPath
                        ldLibs.add(libPath)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    // You can modify the NDK configuration for each variant.
    components.android {
        binaries.afterEach { binary ->
            binary.mergedNdkConfig.cppFlags.add(
                    "-DVARIANT=\"" + binary.name + "\"")
        }
    }

    // Configures source set directory.
    android.sources {
        test {
            java {
                source {
                    srcDirs += 'src/test/java'
                }
            }
            assets {
                source {
                    srcDirs += '../../../assets/'
                }
            }
        }
        androidTest {
            java {
                source {
                    srcDirs += 'src/instrumentTest/java'
                }
            }
            res {
                source {
                    srcDirs += 'src/instrumentTest/res'
                }
            }
        }

        main {
            java {
                source {
                    srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
                    srcDirs += '../../../third-party/assetbridge/src/'
                }
            }
            assets {
                source {
                    srcDirs += '../../../assets/'
                }
            }
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs += '../../../third-party/assetbridge/jni/'
                    srcDirs += '../../../lib/'
                    exclude '**/*Test*'
                    srcDirs += '../../common/'
                    srcDirs += 'src/main/jni'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
    //testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Hamcrest matching
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

the output is
http://pastebin.com/A06DhkWJ

Comment: what is the output of `gradle clean build --info --stacktrace`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A06DhkWJ